# RadioButton checked sate automatically changes on scrolling event of RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am facing problem with my RadioButton in RecyclerView item. According to the 'type' I changes the checked RadioButton. But after all data loaded, then when I click the non checked radio button it's get checked. But after scrolling the checked radio button which I just clicked that goes unchecked. I want the button which I just clicked to be checked. But it is doesn't stays checked. How do I get what I want? Can anyone please help me!!!!!!!

**This is my Adapter Class:**

```
public class AttendanceAdapterLocal extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<AttendanceAdapterLocal.ViewHolder>{
    private ArrayList<StudentAttendance> attendanceArrayList;
    private Context context;

    public AttendanceAdapterLocal(ArrayList<StudentAttendance> attendanceArrayList) {
        this.attendanceArrayList = attendanceArrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_mark_attendance, viewGroup, false);
        context = viewGroup.getContext();
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        final String type = attendanceArrayList.get(i).getType();
        final String id = attendanceArrayList.get(i).getId();
        final String name = attendanceArrayList.get(i).getName();
        final String roll = attendanceArrayList.get(i).getRoll();
        viewHolder.setData(name, roll, type, id);

        final DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        final User user = new AccessStorage(context).getUserDetails();
        final String userId = user.getUserId();
        viewHolder.radioPresent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (databaseHelper.updateStudentAttendanceData(id, userId, "P", "0") > 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Marked successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    viewHolder.radioPresent.setChecked(true);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to mark attendance.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
        viewHolder.radioAbsent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (databaseHelper.updateStudentAttendanceData(id, userId, "A", "0") > 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Marked successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    viewHolder.radioAbsent.setChecked(true);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to mark attendance.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
        viewHolder.radioNone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (databaseHelper.updateStudentAttendanceData(id, userId, "NA", "0") > 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Marked successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    viewHolder.radioNone.setChecked(true);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to mark attendance.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return attendanceArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // Widgets
        private TextView textName;
        private RadioGroup radioGroup;
        private RadioButton radioPresent, radioAbsent, radioNone;
        // Vars
        private View view;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            view = itemView;

            textName = view.findViewById(R.id.textName);
            radioGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
            radioPresent = view.findViewById(R.id.radioPresent);
            radioAbsent = view.findViewById(R.id.radioAbsent);
            radioNone = view.findViewById(R.id.radioNone);
        }

        private void setData(String name, String roll, final String type, final String id) {
            textName.setText(roll + ". " + name);

            if (type.equals("P")) {
                radioPresent.setChecked(true);
            } else if(type.equals("A")) {
                radioAbsent.setChecked(true);
            }else if(type.equals("NA")) {
                radioNone.setChecked(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a small mistake . In your onClick method , while changing the state just notify the adapter .

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (databaseHelper.updateStudentAttendanceData(id, userId, "P", "0") > 0) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Marked successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                viewHolder.radioPresent.setChecked(true);
            //Notify adapter 
             attendanceArrayList.notify();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to mark attendance.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

I can see , everywhere you have done the same thing .Its important to notify the adapter while changing anything in the list . You either use         notifyDataSetChanged() or         notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition);

Comment: If I use notifyDataSetChange(), then RadioButton.setChecked(true) is not working. Showing error: ViewHolder{c09a21c position=0 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 invalid update undefined adapter position}

Comment: For that you need to update your database for that corresponding value . Then it will work for sure . While checking the radio button , we are just making ui change not the data change in database or list .

Comment: Do add a check for if(adapterposition != -1). i will be the position in which you have to make change .

Answer (score 0):

If you still face the problem you should create a [Model](http://www.example.com/) class.

Comment: I am using Model class. What did u mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Use Interface on click of the radio buttons, make necessary changes in your original list that you are passing in recycler view(Inside Activity) then use notifiDataSetChanged() method.